# Move UIView at same rate when keyboard is displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, uikeyboard

I have a UIView in the center of my screen that contains a `UISearchBar`. When the user clicks on the `UISearchBar` I successfully animate this view up based on `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`.

The problem is is that this isn't good enough for me.

What I'd like to do is keep the `UIView` there until the keyboard top touches the bottom of the `UIView`, then move the UIView up at the same rate the keyboard is moving. Essentially "pinning" the `UIView` to the top of the keyboard once the keyboard reaches the `UIView`.

I'm beginning to think this isn't possible with the information the `UIKeyboard` notifications send out. Anyone tried anything similar and seen success?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the information provided in the `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` to for this. The information in this notification tells you the beginning and ending frames for the keyboard, the type of animation curve, and the duration.

To calculate the point of the keyboard at any given time in the animation, you can either use [this code](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com.au/2010/12/more-animation-curves-than-you-can.html) from Jeff LaMarche, or use the [`CAMediaTimingFunction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) class and plug in the animation type (into function with name) and figure out where the keyboard should be at certain points in time.

Once you know where the keyboard will be at a given point in time, you can set up an animation for your `UIView` to move with the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `CAMediaTimingFunction`. I'm not sure how I'd make sure my timer and the keyboard timer were started at the same time. I realized this really doesn't fit in with the design anymore (for example it never happens on an iPhone 5 so it's a moot point.